# Get slider's value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dragdealer-js

I created a slider using [Dragdealer](http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/) and I'm having a problem reading the slider's value.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="just-a-slider" class="dragdealer">
    <div class="handle red-bar">
        <span class="value"></span>%
    </div>
</div>
```

and Javascript to enable the slider:

```
new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
  animationCallback: function(x, y) {
    $('#just-a-slider .value').text(Math.round(x * 100));
  }
});
```

How to read the value the user has selected?

For example I want to do something like that:

```
var sliderValue = document.getElementById("just-a-slider").value;

// When the user clicks the Apply button an empty div gets the slider's value that the user selected
var greetingString = sliderValue;
document.getElementById("users_choice").innerText = greetingString;
```

Comment: Go read read what's on http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/ first. It's pretty difficult to be clearer than that. Unless you're really new to javascript or programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3u5G8/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="just-a-slider" class="dragdealer">
    <div class="handle red-bar">
        <span class="value"></span>%
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Get slider value" id="button1" />
```

**jQuery**

```
new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
  animationCallback: function(x, y) {
    $('#just-a-slider .value').text(Math.round(x * 100));
  }
});

$('#button1').click(function(){
    alert($('#just-a-slider .value').text());
});
```

[**Live demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u5G8/)

Comment: `$('#just-a-slider .value').text();` did the job.

Comment: If this solves your problem than you may mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#users_choice').text() = $('#just-a-slider .value').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation at http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/ it seems you can simply do

```
var sliderValue = $('#just-a-slider').getValue();
```

> **getValue** - Get the value of a Dragdealer instance programatically. The value is returned as an [x, y] tuple and is the equivalent of the projected value returned by the regular callback, not animationCallback.

Comment: I tried it and I got the following error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'getValue'`